# Application closes without a reason

Tags: c#, db2

My applications quit for no reason without a error, it just stops, and I don't see why this happens. Whenever I go through it in the debug mode, it stops on the line `database.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
database.con.Open();
using(database.cmd = new iDB2Command(query, database.con))
{
   database.cmd.CommandText = query;

   foreach(var value in para)
   {
      database.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(value.Key, value.Value);
   }

   database.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
database.con.Close();
```

My query wasn't correct, rather thought it was the connection, so I searched in the wrong place...
anyways, thanks for the help guys :-)

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the Application Event Log? How do you handle exceptions in your app?

Comment: I don't know, I thougt maybe there is something in ther I oversaw.
There is no exception thrown.

Comment: It's very possible that an exception occurs in your code which you don't catch.

Comment: Have you checked to see that it does not throw an InvalidOperationException? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep. Check the Application Event Log. Whatever is there can help you narrow down your problem. Also, what makes you think that no exception is thrown. You might not see it, but it could be the reason for the app to terminate.

Comment: Is this a Silverlight app or do you use a service to communicate with your database? And is this a Mysql db?

Comment: Activation context generation failed for "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_0c178a139ee2a7ed\MFC80U.DLL". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Is the error in the Application Event log

it's a DB2

Comment: dependent dll is missing

Comment: Set the connection in another application as the same, and there it works correctly, so I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Put your whole code into TRY CATCH block and then print the Exception message in a Label or Popup. This will help you get the exact error being thrown. While in debug mode, you can see the details of this error on the `Exception e` part.

```
try
{
    //your code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Label1.Text = e.Message;
}
```

The issue may be with your Database Instance.

Comment: Doesn't work, there is no exception thrown so I got nothing to catch (anyway tested, but did nothing)